# Drupal 8 Webform Composite fieldset

Tags: webforms

Is there a way to add fieldsets inside of a custom composite? Not looking to add anything repeatable, just simply group the fields together.

This get's the fieldset to show but I don't know how to add fields as children.

```
$elements['grouped_fields'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Grouped Fields')
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the fields inside of the fieldset:

```
$elements['grouped_fields']['field1'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Field 1'),
];
$elements['grouped_fields']['field2'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Field 2'),
];
// ...
```

Comment: Boom! You rock.